# Can´t find jbpm workbench distribution zip to deploy in tomcat7

Tags: tomcat7, jbpm, kie-workbench

I'm trying to deploy jbpm 6.2.0 on kie-workbench in tomcat7

In [jbpm documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/ch09.html#wb.Installation) it says:

> From the workbench distribution zip, take the kie-wb-*.war that corresponds to your application server:
>
> jboss-as7: tailored for JBoss AS 7 (which is being renamed to WildFly in version 8)
>
> tomcat7: the generic war, works on Tomcat and Jetty

I just can´t find the **workbench distribution zip**, googling I found this: [github repository](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/blob/master/kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars/pom.xml), but It contains a lot of Maven projects with no instructions to build the wars.

Also I found in maven central an artifact with the following description:

> This module builds the download wars for different application servers.

But still I don´t know how to use it to create the war file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss/org/kie/kie-wb-distribution-wars/6.2.0.Final/

You might want to follow installation instructions here as well:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/blob/master/kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars/src/main/assembly/tomcat7/README.txt